# Understanding Django ForeignKey relationships in inline formsets

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms

I am building a simple app around firewall policy change requests. I am having a hard time understanding how I should setup my models and forms so that a rule request can be made all in one view.

Here is a simplified version of my models and forms to get to the root of the issue. I am using a few foreign keys from `RuleRequest` to `Address` as this is my understanding of how to do a One-to-Many relationship in that a `RuleRequest` can have many source and destination `Address`'s but an `Address` will only have one `RuleRequest`.

```
# Models
class Address(CreatedUpdatedModel):

    ipv4_address = IPAddressField(null=True)


class RuleRequest(CreatedUpdatedModel):

    sources = models.ForeignKey(Address, related_name='rule_requests_source', null=True)
    destinations = models.ForeignKey(Address, related_name='rule_requests_destination', null=True)


# Forms
class AddressForm(BootstrapMixin, forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = Address
        fields = [
            'ipv4_address'
        ]


class RuleRequestForm(BootstrapMixin, forms.ModelForm):

    sources = inlineformset_factory(RuleRequest, Address, AddressForm, fk_name='rule_requests_source')
    destinations = inlineformset_factory(RuleRequest, Address, AddressForm, fk_name='rule_requests_destination')

    class Meta:
        model = RuleRequest
        fields = [
            'sources', 'destinations',
        ]
```

As of now, I get:

`ValueError: 'firewall.Address' has no field named 'rule_requests_source'.`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are doing it backward.  The ForeignKey field should be on the many side of the one-to-many.

Since an Address can only have one RuleRequest, Address should have the ForeignKey field.

And there is no need to pass the `fk_name` or `related_name` parameters.  These are used for other purposes:  `fk_name` is used when you are joining related models on a field other than pk (id), which you are not doing here.. Django joins by `id` unless told otherwise, and you should let it do that unless you have a specific reason. And `related_name` is used to change the name of the reverse relationship from the default.. which is not relevant to your situation here either.

Comment: So how would I track the difference between source and destination in `RuleRequest` and how would I get an aggregate of the addresses given an instance of `RuleRequest`?

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by 'track the difference'?  But how you would get the addresses.. that's where related_name can come in.  `myrulerequest.adress_set.all()` would give you a queryset containing all addresses related to the rule.

Comment: Where `address_set` is Django's default related_name for that relation.  If you want to change it to something more elegant.. you could set `related_name="addresses"`, then your code would look like `myrulerequest.addresses.all()`.  But you don't need to use the related name in your form/formset code.

Comment: Well a `RuleRequest` is made up of both source and destination addresses. That is why I was using `related_name` because I had two foreign keys to the `Address` model, one for sources and one for destinations.

Comment: You can also do a more straightforward lookup.. assuming you have a ForeignKeyField in Address called `rule_request`: `Address.objects.filter(rule_request=myrulerequest)` would give you the same queryset as above

Comment: Wait, so a rule has just one source address and just one destination address?  Or many of each?

Comment: Well, if an address can be both a source and a destination, like maybe it's the source of one and the destination of another rule.. use two FK fields in Address with different related_name on each.  If it can't be both, then maybe you just want a single fk relationship with a boolean specifying if it's a source or destination?

Answer (score 0):

actually One-To-Many relation is form Address to RuleRequest.A source or destinations can have one address but an address can have many of them.